# Rewrite rule with two $_GET

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /art/art.php?galerie=$1
```

So thanks to this I can access the different galeries that exist : 
website.com/art/sun or website.com/art/beach for example ( as long as the galerie exists otherwise returns a error message saying page doesn't exists)

This all works fine up to here .

But i needed to add a `$_Get` on the page also :
website.com/sun?row=2 for example.

But i cannot do this as sun?row=2 isn't a registered galerie ...
How do I get around this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the QSA (Query String Append) flag to forword  new query strings to the target :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /art/art.php?galerie=$1 [QSA]
```

Now This will rewrite

- /foo?querystring

to

/art/art.php?galerie=foo&querystring